# Can Plupload bypass Cloudflare's 100 mb upload limit?

Tags: cloudflare, plupload

I am trying to upload files that are larger than 100 MB through Cloudflare's network. 
I want everything to run through Cloudflare's network because I don't want my website's IP to be known to the world.

Plupload can be used to chunk files before uploading them to the server. 
This is what it says on Plupload's home page.

> Upload in Chunks
>
> Files that have to be uploaded can be small or huge - about several
>   gigabytes in size. In such cases standard upload may fail, since
>   browsers still cannot handle it properly. We slice the files in chunks
>   and send them out one by one. You can then safely collect them on the
>   server and combine into original file.
>
> As a bonus this way you can overcome a server's constraints on
>   uploaded file sizes, if any.

The last part is what catches my eyes.

So can I use Plupload to bypass the 100 MB limit set by Cloudflare?

Comment: I don't think so. The limit set by Cloudflare is limited for complete files. Chunks are not complete files (yet) but it is all send in one request, so the limit will be retained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested this out and you **can** pass CloudFlare's limit by using plupload's chunking. CloudFlare limits a single file upload that is over 100MB so if we chunk it to say 90MB we would be sending 90MB file through CloudFlare's and that's not an issue.

Comment: Are you able to send the code you used? I'm interested to see how it looks.

Comment: @Antoine I don't have any examples anymore. I do remember using some of the examples they had in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, chunking your uploads can work, I used ResumableJS to get around the upload limit.